# set AfterLabelTextTpl after form render

Tags: extjs4, extjs

I have a form with dynamic fields. In the afterrender event of the form I want to set the afterLabelTextTpl property. I can set this property but I can't see it change in my form. How can I achieve this?

Snippet:

```
listeners: {
    beforerender: function () {
        var fields = me.getForm().getFields();
        Ext.each(fields.items, function (f, idx) {
            f.afterLabelTextTpl = requiredTpl;

            console.log(f.afterLabelTextTpl);
        }); //eo Ext.each
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
I was looking for the **beforerender** method

Comment: @sunny Yes. No result on screen. Btw since Ext4 doLayout() is no longer required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use this property after the component is already rendered. 
The initRenderTpl (which makes use of the label templates) method is run only if the component is not yet rendered. Once its rendered it will not run again.

You will need to update the DOM directly.

Comment: Alright, makes sense. `...getForm().getFields()` is not available before that so I need another way to get all fields. Do you know a way?

Comment: Not really. Are you sure getFields are not available in beforerender event?

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
f.labelEl.dom.innerHTML = "LABEL:<span style='color:red;font-weight:bold' data-qtip='Required'>*</span>";
```

Comment: Wow, it's funny because I need this snippet today :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend something like this in your form:

```
setRequired: function(field, index) {
    field.afterLabelTextTpl = requiredTpl;
},

initComponent: function(arguments) {
    var me = this;

    this.on('beforeadd', function(me, field){
        var fields;

        if (field.isXType('fieldset')) {
            fields = field.query('field');
            Ext.each(fields, me.setRequired);
        } else {
            me.setRequired(field);
        }
    });


    // rest of logic
    me.callParent(arguments);
},
```